# how to deploy static js application on AWS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, cross-domain

I have rest services deployed on aws. now I'd like to deploy a frontend. it's a reactjs app. build produces a folder with html and assets.

now i'd like to host this app on aws and let it talk to my rest services there. does aws offer some dedicated solution for that (static hosting under same domain to avoid cross-origin issues) or i have to build something custom? like putting files on s3 or bundling together with my rest services?

Comment: why don't you use create-react-app ? and deploy your front as a standalone nodejs with minimal express server ? find your happiness here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Comment: I would recommend going for S3 and Cloudfront.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy and host your React app using S3 and CloudFront:

1. Create an S3 bucket for your app (e.g., `myapp.example.com`). Don't assign any public read access permissions to your bucket, not yet.
2. Copy the content of your React `./build` directory to your S3 bucket.
3. Create a CloudFront Web distribution with an S3 origin that points to your S3 bucket. Set the **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** to `myapp.example.com`.
4. Under **Origin Settings** > Set **Restrict Bucket Access** to `Yes` and create a new Origin Access Identity. (*Don't let CloudFront to grant read permissions on your bucket. You'll do it manually in the coming steps*)
5. Under **Error Pages**, add a new error response for `403 Forbidden`, set the **Customize Error Response** to `Yes`, **Response Page Path** to `/index.html` and **HTTP Response Code** to `200 OK`.
6. Using your DNS provider, add a `CNAME` record for `myapp.example.com` that points to your CloudFront distribution's domain name (e.g., `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net`). *NOTE: This can be done with an `ALIAS` A host record in Route 53.*
7. Add the following bucket policy to your app bucket in S3 (where XXXXXXXXXXXXX is your Origin Access Identity ID created in step 4 above. This value can be found under **Security** in CloudFront home page's left sidebar):

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2008-10-17",
       "Id": "Policy1415003215468",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt1415003056675",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
               },
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp.example.com/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   *This will deny access to your app using direct S3 URLs. It will allow access via CloudFront only.*
8. Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your REST API configuration to `http://myapp.example.com`.

   **ENABLE AND ENFORCE SSL**
9. In your CloudFront's **Distribution Settings**, select your custom SSL certificate.
10. Under **Behaviors**, set the **Viewer Protocol Policy** for your default behavior to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`.
11. Change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your REST API configuration to `https://myapp.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudFront and S3 to deploy react application. Currently, there is no direct way to setup CloudFront to handle React Routes (If the page is reloaded to serve the index page). For this, as a workaround, you can use error routes in CloudFront to handle this.

For more details on setting up the CloudFront distribution and S3 buckets, refer the article on [Deploying Angular/React Apps in AWS](https://codeburst.io/deploying-angular-react-apps-in-aws-ec55a4fb7446). You can also use the CloudFormation **Launch Stack** button in the article to provision the entire setup.

To set up the full stack application including the Restful APIs, refer [Full Stack Serverless Web Apps with AWS](https://medium.com/99xtechnology/full-stack-serverless-web-apps-with-aws-189d87da024a).